# How to use @ConfigurationProperties with Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, configurationproperties

I have this custom object:

```
data class Pair(
        var first: String = "1",
        var second: String = "2"
)
```

And now I want to autowire it with my `application.yml`:

```
my-properties:
my-integer-list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
my-map:
  - "abc": "123"
  - "test": "test"
pair:
  first: "abc"
  second: "123"
```

Using this class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
class ComplexProperties {
    lateinit var myIntegerList: List<Int>
    lateinit var myMap: Map<String, String>
    lateinit var pair: Pair
}
```

Before adding `Pair` it worked ok, but after I only get `Reason: lateinit property pair has not been initialized`

This is my `main`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@RestController
class MyRestController(
        val props: ComplexProperties
) {
    @GetMapping
    fun getProperties(): String {

        println("myIntegerList: ${props.myIntegerList}")
        println("myMap: ${props.myMap}")
        println("pair: ${props.pair}")

        return "hello world"
    }
}
```

With java I already accomplished this, but I can't see what's missing here.

Comment: Why are you writing your own `Pair` when Kotlin has one already? And why use ambiguous names `first` and `second` for configuration? I think this question suffers from the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well, because with Kotlin's `Pair` I had the same error. So I tried to create one on my own. But it presented the same behavior. I just copied from original `Pair`. Do you have any working case with this condition, using Kotlin's `Pair`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with a lateinit var.

The solution is to either init your pair property to null:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
class ComplexProperties {
    ...
    var pair: Pair? = null
}
```

Or instantiate your pair with default values:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
class ComplexProperties {
    ...
    var pair = Pair()
}
```

You can now autowire it with your application.yml:

```
...
pair:
  first: "abc"
  second: "123"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use `@ConstructionBinding` annotation. It will initialize property using constructor so there is no need for nullability of default value.

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("my-properties")
class ComplexProperties (
    val pair: Pair
)
```